# Showing $\int_0 ^{x_1}(1-z)^{1/2}z^{1/\nu -1}dz = \frac{\Gamma(1/\nu)\Gamma(3/2) }{\Gamma(1/\nu +3/2)}$

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I encountered the following integral:
$$
\int_0 ^{x_1}(1-z)^{1/2}z^{1/\nu -1}dz.
$$
My textbook claims that the solution can be found on a integral table, and is
$$
\frac{\Gamma(1/\nu)\Gamma(3/2) }{\Gamma(1/\nu +3/2)}.
$$
However, I would love to be able to get to this answer somehow. I know that the Gamma function is defined as
$$
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{z-1}dx.
$$
While there are some similarities, I can't really think of how to connect these two. I have also been unable to find the integral on any table of integrals, so any help would be greatly appreciated

**Edit:**

Based on a suggestion, I tried using the incomplete Beta function:
$$
B_x(z,y)=\int_0 ^x t^{z-1}(1-t)^{y-1}dt=\frac{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(y}{\Gamma(z+y)}.
$$
And with $z=1/\nu$ and $y=3/2$, I get
$$
B_x(z,y)=\int_0 ^1 t^{1/\nu-1}(1-t)^{1/2}dt=\frac{\Gamma(1/\nu)\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(1/\nu+3/2)},
$$
which is what I am looking for.

Comment: [Wolfram has you covered](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) for the derivation of the beta integral from the gamma integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x=1$, you obtain the result using the beta function.

Now, for $0 < x <1$ and $\nu >0$ the result is given by
$$\int_0 ^{x}(1-z)^{1/2}z^{1/\nu -1}\,dz=B_x\left(\frac{1}{\nu },\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ where appears the   [incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html)